# Можно ли найти речевые ошибки в приведенном предложении?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, выбор-слов, стилистика

В статье о грамотной речи был рассказан такой случай. Девушка пришла на собеседование с будущим начальником  и практически уже была одобрена (два языка, владеет делопроизводством, работала в очень приличных фирмах), но подвела ее одна фраза: ***«Ой, какой у вас грандиозный вид на город!»*** После этого собеседование было очень быстро закончено.

Я была уверена, что дело **в самом предложении.** Выглядит оно нормально, но мне чем-то не понравилось, а при дальнейшем размышлении оно не нравилось мне всё больше и больше – **как будто  каждое слово  было там не на месте.** И в то же время возможные неточности не были очевидными, хотя и вызывали дискомфорт. Возможно, это высказывание  в целом не подходило для этой речевой ситуации?

Но оказалось, что дело не в самой фразе, а в произношении  звука Г – филологи называют такой звук «Г фрикативное».

**Значит, с предложением всё в порядке?** А как думаете вы?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Предложение может не нравиться, но технически к нему сложно придраться (в него даже не вставлен предлог "в том числе"). Можно было бы зацепиться за сочетание "**какой грандиозный**" (оно выглядит избыточным) на предмет: нет ли здесь намёка на существование неких "степеней грандиозности", мол бывают *более* и *менее* грандиозные виды, но тот, что у вас, *неописуемо* грандиозен. Но это можно отнести на счёт эмоций (грандиозность вида на город из ваших окон меня *восхитила в высшей степени*). Версия же неподходящего произношения правдоподобна: если пресс-секретарь будет представлять фирму по телефону, может создаться впечатление, что говорят "не из столицы".

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.  К слову «грандиозный» у меня тоже были вопросы. Смотрю в словарь: ГРАНДИОЗНЫЙ,  Огромный, величественный, необычный по своему масштабу, размаху. Г-ое зрелище. Г-ое сооружение. Г-ое строительство. Г-ые замыслы.  Здесь значение метафорическое, но в Нацкорпусе можно найти «грандиозный вид», в то же время обычно  там используется сочетание «просматривается грандиозный вид», то есть оценочное сочетание используется  в описаниях.

Comment: В данной речевой ситуации  ( в диалоге) выглядит как  некоторая вольность, не соответствующая официальному стилю. Также примерно выглядит и междометие ОЙ.  Да и другие замечания найдутся.

Comment: Да, возможно, опыт аналогичной работы должен был научить претендентку сдержанности в официальной обстановке.

Comment: *Версия же неподходящего произношения правдоподобна* - а я вот не могу поверить, что звук 'г' ни разу не был употреблён во время самого интервью :) Или во время интервью девушка старалась произносить его "правильно", а тут вдруг "потеряла контроль"?

Comment: Я дам ссылку на статью, где этот случай описан в деталях, там же есть и другие интересные замечания, в том числе относительно слова "кушать". https://moskvichmag.ru/gorod/esli-zhivete-v-moskve-budte-dobry-govorite-po-moskovski/

Comment: Автор перегибает. Если девушка произносит г фрикативное, значит это ее манера произношения. И эта манера будет прослеживается с самого начала разговора. По поводу кушать и зала автор вообще загнул.

Comment: И еще: при чем официальный стиль? Акцент не может поменяться от стиля речи.

Comment: @Sharon Статью прочитал. Да, ваш первый абзац ввёл меня в заблуждение -- из статьи ясно, что это  была её самая первая фраза.

Comment: @Sharon  Аналогично. Тоже введен в заблуждение "первой" фразой. Остальное - в силе: не по контексту это восклицание. Правда, получается что это все из четвертых уст передано, тоже испорченный телефон мог иметь место.

Answer (score 1):

**Почему мне не понравилось предложение**

До фрикативного «Г» я текст не дочитала и стала искать речевые ошибки в самом предложении.

Сначала обратила внимание на сочетание  **«вид на город»**  – послышалось нечто такое: у вас… вид на город. «Вид на что-то» – это почти как «иметь виды на что-то». Еще есть сочетание «вид на жительство». В любом случае **«у вас… вид на город»**  звучит сомнительно, просторечно как-то.

Про слово **«грандиозный»** и междометие «ой» я уже писала. Такие выражения воспринимаются нормально в разговоре со  сверстниками или уже хорошо знакомыми людьми, но только не для собеседования.

И еще несколько слов о самой **речевой ситуации**, в которой желательно придерживаться **официального стиля** общения. Девушка только что вошла, ей бы скромно сидеть и отвечать на вопросы, а не светскую беседу заводить. А вот уж в конце собеседования, когда официальное знакомство закончено и уже ясны  перспективы, тогда и можно сказать что-то на  эту тему.

Но эту фразу надо бы произнести примерно так: ***"Какой здесь красивый вид из окна!».***  Тогда это будет звучать вежливо, сдержанно, корректно, ненавязчиво.

А вот приведенное высказывание, да и само поведение  сразу выдает провинциальные замашки. Если девушка и работала где-то в крупных фирмах, то вряд ли в столице.

По крайней мере, мне так кажется.

Comment: *Если девушка и работала где-то в крупных фирмах, то вряд ли в столице.* -  в статье об этом сказано прямым текстом: "...работала в очень приличных фирмах, хоть и не в Москве, ..." :)

Comment: Я хотела сказать следующее. Эту информацию могут знать те, кто знаком с ее анкетой, а вот посетители офиса этого знать не должны. Речь и манера поведения должны соответствовать столичным образцам.

Answer (score 0):

Не верю. (С) Станиславский.
Если собеседование шло довольно долго, то "фрикативное Г" должно было проявиться гораздо раньше.
*Какое, кстати, интересно - южнорусское /ɣ/ или украинское /ɦ/, они на самом деле разные, украинское, как ни странно, меньше режет слух, да и в белорусском Г несколько отличается от всех трех упомянутых.*  И не по ситуации фраза, с чего бы этой даме выдавать свои чувства на собеседовании?!

А вот касательно использования слова грандиозный в значении "преккрасный", "великолепный" имею вопросы. Это разговорный вариант, едва ли не просторечный.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Собеседование там проходило так:  Девушка является. Друг приглашает сесть. Лилия благодарит, смотрит в окно, улыбается: «Ой, какой у вас грандиозный вид на город!» Получается, что фрикативное Г  прозвучало в ПЕРВОЙ ЖЕ  фразе.  В словаре у наречия «грандиозно» стоит пометка (разг.),  но  прилагательное «грандиозный»  в данном случае примерно того же стиля, я его сначала посчитала сленговым. И еще интересно: если человек знает два иностранных языка, то  как фрикативный звук вписывается в их фонетику?

Comment: Да, я уже прочитал. как дело было.

Comment: Вот насчет словаря... Я не вижу подходящего значения у прилагательного "грандиозный". Ваша экстраполяция на него значения наречия не представлячется убедительной. Но, собственно, даже если принять вашу версию, то мои вопросы не снимаются, скорее наоборот. Использование такого разговорного словечка на собеседовании говорит о пробелах если не  филологической подготовки, то этикетной.

Comment: Да, конечно, мне оно тоже кажется неуместным.